# odoo is not showing up properly

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I use odoo9 on windows and I run it with pycharme with the following configuration [image]

But when i use the address 'localhost: 8069' odoo is not displaying properly. I noticed in the console there are lines that display 404 and I do not know how to fix them. Even i tried to create a new database but every time it doesn't not shows correctely .Any idea for help please ??[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently you don't have less in the system So odoo front end  couldn't work  with out it. 
You need to install NodeJS:

> Less CSS via nodejs on Windows, install nodejs, reboot (to update the
>   PATH) and install less:

```
C:\> npm install -g less
C:\> npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
```

Comment: i'have done that  but it shows always "could not execute command lessc"

Comment: Please restart Odoo server now

Comment: Or you simply reboot your system that will resolve your problem.

Comment: Always the same problem

Comment: There is no diffrence